# app:checkDebugAarMetadata' uses this output of task @react-native-voice_voice:writeDebugAarMetadata' without declaring explicit or implicit dependency

Tags: react-native, voice, react-native-voice

C:\Users\L A T I T U D E\Accutalk\android>gradlew build

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

> Task :@react-native-voice_voice:lintReportDebug
> Wrote HTML report to file:///C:/Users/L%20A%20T%20I%20T%20U%20D%20E/Accutalk/node_modules/@react-native-voice/voice/android/build/reports/lint-results-debug.html

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' (type 'CheckAarMetadataTask').

  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\L A T I T U D E\Accutalk\node_modules@react-native-voice\voice\android\build\intermediates\aar_metadata\debug\aar-metadata.properties'.

    Reason: Task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' uses this output of task ':@react-native-voice_voice:writeDebugAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Declare task ':@react-native-voice_voice:writeDebugAarMetadata' as an input of ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
    2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-voice_voice:writeDebugAarMetadata' from ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' using Task#dependsOn.
    3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-voice_voice:writeDebugAarMetadata' from ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' using Task#mustRunAfter.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 35s
84 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 81 up-to-date

I stuck at this , can somebody know this error, please help me .